# Problem setting Fieldframe path on EE 1.x site

Tags: fieldtype

I'm trying to recreate an EE 1.7 site locally under MAMP but whenever I enter the correct Fieldframe path, I get a blank page in the CP with:

> Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 85 of 99 bytes in /system/core/core.extensions.php on line 235
>
> Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array in /system/extensions/ext.fieldframe.php on line 301

Without the correct path the CP renders but I still get the notices above as well as these ones:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /system/core/core.extensions.php:235) in /system/core/core.functions.php on line 752
>
> Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 85 of 99 bytes in /system/cp/cp.utilities.php on line 288

Obviously, I'd like to get Fieldframe working properly because I need to use Matrix. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally bootstrap the EE1 config with https://gist.github.com/3188642

Assume you have the latest FF?

Comment: Thought I did but turns out there was a more recent version and upgrading to it has sorted the problem. :)